# How to extract third column from multiple lines using perl split?

Tags: regex, perl, split

To extract the third column from the sentence of multiple lines in a file I tried using `map` and `split`. I get the fine result and I tried to extract only using split:

```
#!usr/local/bin/perl 
@arr=<DATA>;  
foreach $m (@arr)
{
@res=split(/\s+/,$m[3]);
print "@res\n";
}
```

---

```
__DATA__
the time is 9.00am
the time is 10.00am
the time is 11.00am
the time is 12.00am
the time is 13.00pm
```

Comment: Yet another example where `use strict` and `use warnings` would have got you a lot closer to a solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your example you are taking the whole data in array and trying to `split $m[3]` i.e you are referring `$m` as array, where `$m`is scalar. When you will use `use strict` and `use warnings`,
then you will get error:

```
Global symbol "@m" requires explicit package name at data.pl
```

That's why you are not getting your output. You should try this:

```
#!usr/local/bin/perl 
use strict;
use warnings;


my @arr=<DATA>;
foreach my $m (@arr)
{
my @res=split(/\s+/,$m); # $m will contain each line of file split it with one or more spaces
print "$res[3]\n"; # print the fourth field
}
```

A shorter version will be:

```
print ((split)[3]."\n") while(<DATA>);
```

Output:

```
9.00am
10.00am
11.00am
12.00am
13.00pm
```

Comment: Right but from the OP point, I guess he wants 4th field. The third field is `is` which is quite redundant and useless

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Perl one liner to extract a column (note: this will work for whitespace delimited file only):

```
perl -ane "print qq(@F[3]\n)" filename.txt
```

Output:

```
9.00am
10.00am
11.00am
12.00am
13.00pm
```

See [perlrun](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html) to understand execution the Perl interpreter.